# In Flutter How to use Providers with AMQP?

Tags: flutter, dart, amqp, provider

in Flutter -which I just recently begin to use-, I am trying to use an AMQP stream using `dart_amqp: ^0.1.4` and use providers `provider: ^3.1.0+1` to make the data available throughout the app.

Only after logging in I start the AMQP service.
The AMQP part works without any issues, I get the data but I never manage to use it with Providers.

**main.dart**

```dart
class BigBrother extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<EventsModel>(create: (_) => EventsModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<EventsModel, DeviceState>(
          create: (_) => new DeviceState(),
          update: (context, eModel, deviceState) {
            deviceState.updateFromEvent(eModel.value);
          },
       ),
     ],
```

My models in **models.dart**
(As seen in below code, I also tried to used StreamProvider and commented it out)

```dart
// Global data model
class DeviceState with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> state = {};
  DeviceState() {
    this.state['xxx'] = {};
    this.state['yyy'] = {};
  }

  updateFromEvent(EventsItemModel event) {
    if (event != null && event.type != null) {
      switch (event.type) {
        case 'heartbeat':
          this.state[event.device][event.type] = event.createdAt;
          break;
        case 'metrics':
          this.state[event.device][event.type] = {}
            ..addAll(this.state[event.device][event.type])
            ..addAll(event.message);
          break;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}


class EventsModel with ChangeNotifier {
  EventsItemModel value;
  bool isSubscribed = false;
  AMQPModel _amqp = new AMQPModel();
  // final _controller = StreamController<EventsItemModel>();

  EventsModel();

  // Stream<EventsItemModel> get stream => _controller.stream;

  _set(String jsonString) {
    value = new EventsItemModel.fromJson(jsonString);

//    _controller.sink.add(value); // send data to stream
//    Provider.of<DeviceState>(context, listen: false).updateFromEvent(value);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  subscribe() {
    if (!this.isSubscribed) {
      this.isSubscribed = true;
      this._amqp.subscribeEvents(_set); // start AMQP service after login
    }
  }
}
```

So on the **login.dart** view, on button pressed and validating the login, I start the AMQP stream:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    print("Login button onPressed");
    Provider.of<EventsModel>(context, listen: false)
                          .subscribe();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.live);
}
```

And lastly the view after successful login:

```dart
class _LivePageState extends State<LivePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DeviceState deviceState = Provider.of<DeviceState>(context);

    print('#### Device state updated');
    print(deviceState.state['xxx']);
```

In the above code, **deviceState** is always null.

So after trying many combination of various Providers, I am still unable to make this work.

Would be glad to have someone's insight on this.

Best regards!